# Saving files to a folder with a numeric system C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am having some trouble with my program. Is there anyway to store an array to a file but every file have a different name. For Example:
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
I am using Visual Studio 2019 and Coding in C#. This is some of the code im using:

```
string selectedsite = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        string selectedsize = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox2.SelectedItem);
        string selectedproduct = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox3.SelectedItem);
        string selectedproxies = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox4.SelectedItem);
        string selectedprofiles = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox5.SelectedItem);
        string path = "d:\\bot\\bot\\Task.txt";
        string[] FileInfo = { selectedsite," ",  selectedsize, " ", selectedproduct, " ", selectedproxies, " ", selectedprofiles };
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and post an [mcve]. The direct answer to your question is 'yes'.  Do you want to store the same data in every file or each element of the array in a different file? What have you tried? You'll need to create the numbered file names. Search the google for `int.ToString`. Do you know how to write a loop?

Comment: What does that code have to do with your description of the problem? Please read [ask] and then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-5.0) method to store an array to a file and every file have a different name.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
 int count = 1;
 string path =@"C:\Users\Desktop\Test\{0}.txt";
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            while (System.IO.File.Exists(string.Format(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Test\{0}.txt", count)))
            {
                count++;
            }
                string selectedsite = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
                string selectedsize = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox2.SelectedItem);
                string selectedproduct = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox3.SelectedItem);
                string selectedproxies = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox4.SelectedItem);
                string selectedprofiles = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox5.SelectedItem);
                string[] FileInfo = { selectedsite, " ", selectedsize, " ", selectedproduct, " ", selectedproxies, " ", selectedprofiles };
                var newFileName = string.Format(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Test\{0}.txt", count);
                count++;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, FileInfo);

 }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How would I then change the name of the file in regards to how many there are. E.G. number 19 - 19.txt

Comment: In my code, the increasing value of count is used as the file name.
In other words, clicking the button will save the array to the file, and the file name will continue to increase from 1.
So what do you mean by changing the file name? Please explain in detail.

Comment: I showed my test results above and it worked fine. Please check your code in detail and provide more code to reproduce the situation.

Comment: I'd use string interpolation `$"Foo {bar}"` rather than `string.Format()` in this day & age.

Comment: I copied you're code but it when the the app is closed it re-writes all the files. I would like a section where it checks to see if the file exists so it does not re-write a file it will just carry on the count. Sorry for my bad description :) thanks for your help!

Comment: I reproduced the problem via the code example you provided in this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68968280/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c and I tested AntiqTech's code which can fix the problem. I also re-edited my code example.