# How do I check if a file exists in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am having some trouble with my program. Is there anyway to check if a file exists but when every file have a different name. For Example:
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt.
At the moment, my code creates separate files but when the app is closed and re-opened it re-writes the txt files. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and Coding in C#. This is some of the code I am using:

```
    int Count = 1;
    string path = "D:\\Bot\\Bot\\Tasks\\{0}.txt";
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            Count++;
        }
        string selectedsite = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        string selectedsize = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox2.SelectedItem);
        string selectedproduct = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox3.SelectedItem);
        string selectedproxies = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox4.SelectedItem);
        string selectedprofiles = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox5.SelectedItem);
        string[] FileInfo = { selectedsite, " ", selectedsize, " ", selectedproduct, " ", selectedproxies, " ", selectedprofiles };
        var newFileName = string.Format(@"D:\Bot\Bot\Tasks\{0}.txt", Count);
        Count++;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, FileInfo);


    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome.  I think you should use String.format inside the "if" structure too. :  if (System.IO.File.Exists(string.Format(@"D:\Bot\Bot\Tasks\{0}.txt", Count))).  If you want to keep increasing the count, you should setup a "while"

Comment: it does not unfortunately as the path will need to keep changing.

Comment: this should do the trick : while(System.IO.File.Exists(string.Format(@"D:\Bot\Bot\Tasks\{0}.txt", Count))) {   Count++; }   With this , you will reach a "count" which a corresponding file does not exist

Comment: This is and invalid while statement. Due to making the “string format” line a variable. How could i change it so it will fit in? Sorry i am new to coding and I apologise for my bad description!

Comment: @OlivierRogier The OP already knows about File.Exists. Its problems are different.

Comment: you can create the pathtemp variable before while and update it during the loop:    string pathtemp= string.Format(@"D:\Bot\Bot\Tasks\{0}.txt", Count);   While (System.IO.File.Exists(pathtemp)) {Count++; pathtemp= string.Format(@"D:\Bot\Bot\Tasks\{0}.txt", Count);}

Comment: The goal, as I understand, he wants the code find out the last file create with file name convention and then create the next file down the line. here goes something like this:  first time : it create 1.txt, second time:  it finds that 1.txt exists,  so it creates 2.txt ...  10th time: it finds the 9.txt exists so it creates 10.txt and so forth.

Comment: what's happening to this post ? some of your comments gets erased when I reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

you could try change the "if" at the beginning to a "while" until you get a "count" which corresponds to a non-existing file.

If  I understand your problem correctly, below is the solution I thought of and tested it in an example project:

```
while(System.IO.File.Exists(string.Format(@"D:\Bot\Bot\Tasks\{0}.txt", Count)))
{
  Count++;  
}
```

edit:
I changed it back to my original suggestion which is a valid statement after all.

Comment: Actually I'm gonna change it back to that. I only wrote this because OP said something about a non-valid statement but I'm testing it at the moment and it is working

Answer (score 1):

You could query every file existence in a loop, or you can list all the files in the directory, find the max one and go from there

```
Count = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Bot\Bot\Tasks")
  .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
  .Select(f => int.TryParse((f), out var x) ? x : int.MinValue)
  .Max() + 1;
```